# How to copy the error message from console to file in java?

Tags: java, eclipse

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("test2_output.txt"));

System.setOut(out);
```

This above code is not a correct code.I require this above file should contain error message that is produced in **console**. So what will be the code to get error message from console and copy that message into a file.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the java standard out and standard error to log files.  In fact, here is Oracle's (user submitted blog) answer to your question:

https://blogs.oracle.com/nickstephen/entry/java_redirecting_system_out_and

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this:

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("output.txt"));
System.setOut(out);
```

The second statement is the key.  It changes the value of the supposedly "final" `System.out` attribute to be the supplied PrintStream value.

---

I'd just like to add that it is generally a better idea to use a logging subsystem like [Log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/), [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) or the standard Java [java.util.logging](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-frame.html) subsystem.  These offer such things as fine-grained logging control via runtime configuration files, support for rolling log files, feeds to system logging.

Or, if what you are doing is not "logging", then consider either:

- redirecting standard output to a file on the command line, or
- changing your application to use an `out` stream passed as a parameter rather than writing to `System.out`.

Messing around with (e.g. redirecting) `System.out` is liable to cause nasty surprises for other code in your JVM that is not expecting this to happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this this code for generate logger file.
Following code create file of size 1 Mb.

```
        File dir1 = new File (".");
        String workingDir = dir1.getCanonicalPath();
        FileHandler hand = new FileHandler(workingDir+"\\LOGDATA.log",
        (1024*1024),3);
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("LOGDATA"); 
        SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();  
        hand.setFormatter(formatter);
        logger.addHandler(hand);
        logger.info(workingDir+"\\LOGDATA.log");
```

output :

```
 D:\LOGDATA.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.setErr(out);`

Source: [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setErr(java.io.PrintStream))

Answer (score 0):

Regarding launching app in eclipse, there is an option to write to a console and to a file, by selecting "File" checkbox see: 
[image: eclipse settings]